# yaxis labels are getting repeated in highcharts

Tags: highcharts

Yaxis labels are getting repeated in spline chart. Below is the code used :

```
yAxis: {
                    opposite: false,
                    allowDecimals: true,
                    title : {
                        text : 'Some Text'
                    },
                    labels: {
                        format: '{value:.2f}'



                    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: They are repeated because there is not enough decimal points to show the actual difference. In reality you have `5.890, 5.895, 5.900, 5.905, 5.910, 5.915`. So your options are, either show more decimal points, or limit how many points you have.

Comment: Correction; limit how many labels you have.

Comment: But my y-axis data comprises of only values till 2decimal points like 5.8, 5.89, 5.9, 5.91 etc . So how is high chart considering it to be till 3 decimal digits?

Comment: set `yAxis: { tickInterval: 0.01 }` in your chart, and it should work. Highcharts can calculate what is between 5.89 and 5.9, and because there is enough space, a label is inserted there.

Comment: Thanks it worked for me!!